# Use strict and let not working as expected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I declared variables twice in my function while I am using "use strict". I know this function has global scope and it's variables are also treated as global with window scope i.e window.car

But It should not re-declare speed and capacity variables inside if statement with let data type. ( "let" Declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value. )

```
(function car() {
    "use strict";
    var speed = 100;
    const capacity = '1000CC';

    if(speed)  {
        let speed = 200;
        let capacity = '5000CC';
        console.log(speed,capacity);

    }
    console.log(speed,capacity);

})();
```

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: So what's the issue, I'm getting `200 "5000CC"` from the log, as expected ?

Comment: I think there should be an error. "you can not re-declare speed and capacity in if statement" because i am using "use strict"

Comment: @JahanzaibAslam Not across different scopes as both `let` and `const` are block scoped

Comment: You are not redeclaring the variable, you are initializing a new variable `speed` and `capacity` in the block scope of the ìf` statement).

Comment: @RGraham I know it's blocked scope but speed/capacity variables outside if statement also have scope in if statement. so there should be error you can not redeclare variable while declaring them again inside if statement. what do think?

Comment: **No**. Please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules. Only *Redeclaration of the same variable in the same block scope raises a TypeError.*

Comment: @RGraham Thanks Now I  got this .

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Please also consider RGraham's last comment in your answer. That make sense at least for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"let" Declares a block scope local variable. But still global variable can be modified in local scope.

```
(function car() {
    "use strict";
    var speed = 100;
    const capacity = '1000CC';

    if(speed)  {
        let speed = 200;
        let capacity = '5000CC';
        console.log(speed,capacity);//inside local it is modified to 200

    }
    console.log(speed,capacity);//outside scope it pull from global scope to 100

})();
```

You can re-declare / modify the global variables even in strict mode.

---

You'll only get error when you re-declare the same variable in same scope. Look at the following example taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules)

```
if (x) {
  let foo;
  let foo; // TypeError thrown.
}
```

However, function bodies do not have this limitation! (But it throws an error in ES6 though as commented by @Bergi, may be there's wrong documentation in MDN)

```
function do_something() {
  let foo;
  let foo; // This works fine.
}
```

Comment: But can I re-declare same global variable with let data type inside a block statement while using "use strict"?

Comment: Yes, you can re-declare.

Comment: I think there should be an error. "you can not re-declare speed and capacity variables inside if statement" because i am using "use strict" mode. what do you think?

Comment: "*function bodies do not have this limitation*" is rubbish, it throws an error in ES6 just as well. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @Bergi, I hope you'll modify the mdn documenation?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: MDN is a bit of a problem, since Gecko did implement `let` in JavaScript 1.7 before it was cool, uh, before it was standardised with ES6. The semantics differ a bit unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `speed` declared with `var` and the `speed` declared with `let` are *two different variables*.

Inside the body of the `if` statement, the local declaration of `speed` *hides* the variable declared in the outer block - it doesn't redeclare it.